# Bool Palidrome function in Cstring?

Tags: c

I'm writing a function that tells the user whether their input is a palindrome or not (string backwards as it is forwards. I'm supposed to use a bool function that uses the cstring library that was given to me in which I fill in a while statment to execute the algorithm.

```
bool checkPalindrome(char* cstr)
{
    char* front = cstr;
    char* back = cstr + strlen(cstr)-1;

    while(front < back)
    {
        // i can only change within this while loop
        if(cstr[front] != cstr[back])
        {
            return false;
        }

        front++;
        back++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I honestly don't know if I'm doing this right, I get an "invalid type" error in the if statement within the while loop, because I'm calling a pointer character in an array, which I'm guess I can't do. I wrote a correct function declaring `front` and `back` as integers, but I'm supposed to use this exact function only changing what's within the while statement.

Any comments or advise would be appreciated!

Comment: You want to decrement your back pointer

Comment: `cstr[front]` is not correct (rinse, repeat for `cstr[back]`). And I'm confident even if you were correctly dereferencing using `*front` and `*back`, you don't want to *increment* `back` on each iteration. That thing is supposed to be walking *down*, not up. Also, be careful in considering edge cases (zero length string), where your initial computation of `back` is questionable. Lastly, those pointers should all be `const char*`. There is no reason to expect, nor use, hot pointers in this function.

Answer (score 1):

`front` and `back` of of type `char*`. To compare their values you should dereference the pointer. For example:

```
if (*front != *back)
```

---

Note:

To use `if (cstr[front] != cstr[back])` the `front` and `back` would need to be integral value types (e.g., `int` or `size_t`).

Answer (score 1):

`front` and `back` are pointers to the right location so:

```
if (*front!=*back)
```

also modify the way you move your pointers:

```
front++; // move forwards
back--;  // move backwards
```